# Getting props undefined on Redux axios api call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

For the life of me I can't figure this problem out.  I am trying to display user information, and I know the api is working at 127.0.0.1/api/user/1.  However, when I try to pass in the parameters I keep getting props are undefined.  Here is my router to prove I'm passing in an id

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import ArticleListView from '../containers/ArticleListView'
import ArticleDetailView from '../containers/ArticleDetailView'
import SignUp from '../containers/SignUp'
import UserDetailView from '../components/UserInformation';


const BaseRouter = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ArticleListView} /> 
        <Route exact path='/:cid' component={ArticleDetailView} />
        <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path='/user/:id' component={UserDetailView} />
    </div>
)

export default BaseRouter
```

Here is the action that keeps getting undefined:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {  thunk  }  from 'react-redux'

export function getUser() {


  return dispatch => {

     dispatch(fetchUserBegin());
     const id = this.props.params.match.id
     return axios.get(`/api/user/${id}`)
      .then( res => { 
        dispatch(fetchUserSuccess(res.data)
      )})
      }
 }

export const FETCH_USER_BEGIN   = 'FETCH_USER_BEGIN';
export const FETCH_USER_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_USER_FAILURE = 'FETCH_USER_FAILURE';

export const fetchUserBegin = () => ({
  type: FETCH_USER_BEGIN
});

export const fetchUserSuccess = user => ({
  type: FETCH_USER_SUCCESS,
  payload: { user }
});

export const fetchUserFailure = error => ({
  type: FETCH_USER_FAILURE,
  payload: { error }
});
```

Reducer

```
import {  FETCH_USER_BEGIN, FETCH_USER_SUCCESS, FETCH_USER_FAILURE  } from '../actions/actionTypes'


const initialState = {
    user: {},
    loading: false,
    error: null
  };

  export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_USER_BEGIN:
        // Mark the state as "loading" so we can show a spinner or something
        // Also, reset any errors. We're starting fresh.
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true,
          error: null
        };

      case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
        // All done: set loading "false".
        // Also, replace the items with the ones from the server
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          user: action.user
        };

      case FETCH_USER_FAILURE:
        // The request failed, but it did stop, so set loading to "false".
        // Save the error, and we can display it somewhere
        // Since it failed, we don't have items to display anymore, so set it empty.
        // This is up to you and your app though: maybe you want to keep the items
        // around! Do whatever seems right.
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.payload.error,
          user: {}
        };

      default:
        // ALWAYS have a default case in a reducer
        return state;
    }
  }
```

Store:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    articles: articleReducer
})


const store  = createStore(reducer, composeEnhances(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
))
```

Display component

```
    import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUser } from "../store/actions/userActions";

class UserDetailView extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUser()  //fixed
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    console.log(user)

    return (
      <ul>
        {user.map(user =>
          <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({   //added
  getUser: dispatch(getUser())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(UserDetailView);  //fixed
```

Comment: there could be 2 reasons 
1. you forgot to add reducer to RootReducer
2. forgot to connect and mapStateToProps

Comment: you passed data in Payload but you are directly accessing it , it should be action.payload.user

Comment: added the rest of the code and I'll add payload as wel.

Comment: added payload and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fatch the user data from payload object because getUser method dispatch the data in action.payload.user.

```
case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
        // All done: set loading "false".
        // Also, replace the items with the ones from the server
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          user: action.payload.user
        };
```

Comment: This didn't resolve, but definitely was a problem I missed.  Must have multiple issues.